# Flutter appBar Backbutton doesn't appear

Tags: class, navigation, flutter, appbar

I've successfully navigated to a class in a new file, but now I'm not getting a backbutton on my appBar.  Here is my navigation from main.dart...

```
new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/searchpage');
                },
```

and here is my SearchPage appBar..

```
class SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/loginpage': (BuildContext context) => new Login.LoginPage(),
          '/mainpage': (BuildContext context) => new Main.MyApp(),
        },
        home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          "Search",
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Check Sameh Khemira answer in attached link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60097799/17211037

Answer (score 46):

You should only have one `MaterialApp` at the root of your app. Each `MaterialApp` creates its own `Navigator`, and the existence of multiple routes on the navigation stack is what causes the implicit back button to appear in the `leading` slot of the `AppBar`.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped! It worked by returning a Scaffold in child page widget rather than having it in new MaterialApp.

Answer (score 9):

Remove `NavigationDrawer` from page, where you need to see back button.
If your page specified NavigationDrawer, then hamburger menu will be showed instead of back button.