# Flutter Scaffold Appbar not showing the back button

Tags: flutter, dart

My class is not showing the back button in the AppBar,

Already try put this.automaticallyImplyLeading = true,

```
import 'package:carros/pages/carro/carro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CarroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Carro carro;
  CarroPage(this.carro);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(carro.nome),
      ),
      body: _body(),
    );
  }

  _body() {
    return Image.network(carro.urlFoto);
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you navigate to this widget? For the app bar to show a back button there has to be somewhere to go back to ie. there has to be another (previous) route on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your own back button :

```
     appBar: AppBar(
                    leading: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    iconSize: 20.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _goBack(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text('back')),
```

> And the _goBack method :

```
 _goBack(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.pop(context);
```

}

Answer (score 17):

I used this solution, it works for me, add **leading** inside **AppBar**:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.0,
        titleSpacing: 10.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.black54,
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the document, if you use Material design and push a screen, the back button should be there.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

But sometimes the back button and app bar background color are the same, so it is invisible. Let try to click on the leading button zone or set to a contrary color

```
appBar: AppBar(
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.black, //change your color here
  ),
  title: Text("Sample"),
  centerTitle: true,
),
```

Comment: i'm new to flutter so i don't know - `if you use Material design and push a screen, the back button should be there`, you helped me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

1. you should to be sure a create appbar : AppBar()
2. and should to set a color in the theme until maybe icon is white

Comment: I was having white colour for the whole app bar & the default back button of app bar appears in white only. So silly of me ':)

Answer (score 1):

In order for the back key to come, the part that goes to that page is "Navigator.pushNamed (context, '/ brand new');"
For example, it should be in the form of.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you did not return the Materialapp(); before your scaffold ().
In the class you want to navigate to, return scaffold (); and the back button will be there, for more reference, you can check out this [YouTube video on how to make your Flutter page automatic back button visible](https://youtu.be/AqpY6E5YIVc).

Answer (score 0):

The back buttons were all there by default. I built and deployed, the back buttons are there for some users, not for others. My goodness, this platform is getting buggier and buggier by the day. I shouldn't have to explicitly create a back button and wire in a manual pop function when the documentation clearly states it's part of the gig, and it works on *some* devices under *some* circumstances, with absolutely no consistency. (sigh)

Answer (score 0):

To show back button only with custom color , and appbar background white or any color

```
appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            leading: IconButton(
              color: Colors.black,
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              iconSize: 20.0,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
```

**Result**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following `ThemeData` in my `MaterialApp` widget in order to show the back button:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This Code for show back Arrow:- 
appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Otp Screen"),
              actions: <Widget>[],
              backgroundColor: greenColor,
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                iconSize: 30.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              elevation: 5.0,
              systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to Navigator.pushReplacement. If you use pushReplacement for navigating to a page, there will not be back arrow button whatever you do. Solution is to replace this:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => ProfilePage()));
```

With this:

```
Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => ProfilePage()));
```

And voila, back button will be visible on that page.